# Create a JDialog from a JDialog

Tags: java, jdialog

How can you create a JDialog when you're in a JDialog?

```
DialogTest dialog = new DialogTest(this,true);
```

The above code doesn't work because the first parameter has to be a JFrame, but in this case it's a JDialog.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dialog is awt not the same as JDialog

Comment: @peeskillet, I created the first Dialog from a JFrame, so I could use the this-parameter without problems. Because the fact that the first parameter has to be a Frame, I can't use "this", because "this" is a JDialog...

Comment: and a JDialog is a Dialog and you can use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) constructor

Comment: Oh, I think I've got it, the owner always has to be the first Frame of the application am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many constructors for a JDialog, one of which, will allow you to pass a Dialog.  JDialog is derived from Dialog.

Comment: That answer did it for me! Thank you for all of your time! The next time I will first read the Javadoc accurate ;)